# Google Sheets formula: extend single item in arrayformula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

For simplicity, let's say I have a raw tab with several values in several columns:

Raw tab

```
A    B        C      D
Code Product  Price  Stock
01   Pen      1      yes
02   Pencil   0.8    no
03   Rubber   0.5    no
04   Paper    0.3    yes
```

Now, in another tab I want to filter data from the raw tab, but I want to be able to insert some fixed value to it. Look:

```
=filter({Raw!A:A,Raw!B:B,Raw!C:C},Raw!D:D="yes")
```

This works but I want to add a forth column with a fixed value, as if it was like below

```
=filter({Raw!A:A,Raw!B:B,Raw!C:C, "OK"},Raw!D:D="yes")
```

But this formula above fails with Function

> ARRAY_ROW parameter 4 has mismatched row size. Expected: 601. Actual:
>   1.

I understand that "OK" is just a single item and is not expanded for all the matches from filter, but how to make it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or try:

```
=FILTER({RAW!A:C, RAW!X:X&"OK"}, RAW!D:D="yes")
```

where column X is an empty column

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
=filter({Raw!A:A,Raw!B:B,Raw!C:C, if(Row(Raw!A:A),"OK")},Raw!D:D="yes")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(RAW!A:D, "select A,B,C,'OK' where D = 'yes' label 'OK'''", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: With query I cannot have the same column twice, or apply a formula to a column